# OptionValue in Grails Select with list of domain objects

Tags: grails

I've done some research on how to display a dropdown with an optional value. Currently, I have a list of domain objects (people) in a dropdown. They display with "First name last name".

I want to change the way the names are displayed in a selection. Looking at the g:select API, I see I can use optionValue and optionKey. I've tried, but got nowhere. So here is my current code:

```
<g:select id="allPeople" name="allPeople" from="${dropdown}" />
```

I want the output to be "Last, First". I've tried this:

```
<g:select id="allPeople" optionValue="${it?.last},${it?.first}" from="${dropdown}" name="allPeople" value="" >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A nice way to do it is to add a transient getter on your domain, then use that for the optionValue.

```
class Person {
    String first
    String last

    static transients = ['lastFirst']

    String getLastFirst() {
        "$last, $first"
    }
}
```

then

```
<g:select name="allPeople" optionValue="${it.lastFirst}" from="${dropdown}"/>
```

Comment: Good call - Although I'm getting a problem with the collection passed to the view. It's a List<Person>. But the error indicates I cannot get lastFirst on a null object..

Comment: the error seems to indicate that you have a null object in your List of Persons. `it?.lastFirst` will get you safely past the NPE but you should look at why you have a null in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
optionValue="${{it?.last+', '+it.first}}"
```

This mean that you pass a closure that builds what you need.